# Check if values in list exceed threshold a certain amount of times and return index of first exceedance

Tags: python, list, iterator, threshold

I am searching for a clean and pythonic way of checking if the contents of a list are greater than a given number (first threshold) for a certain number of times (second threshold). If both statements are true, I want to return the index of the first value which exceeds the given threshold.

**Example**:

```
# Set first and second threshold
thr1 = 4
thr2 = 5

# Example 1: Both thresholds exceeded, looking for index (3)
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 8]

# Example 2: Only threshold 1 is exceeded, no index return needed
list2 = [1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Example 1 does not pass your 2nd threshold. There are exactly 5 numbers >4

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think his thresholds are inclusives

Comment: I noted the same, OP uses alternatively 'exceeded' and 'reached' so it's hard to guess what he wants.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Threshold can be greater equal or greater, doesn't really matter, sorry being vague regarding this fact. Will have a closer look at the code answers tomorrow! Already want to thank everyone for the great answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's considered pythonic to abuse the fact that booleans are ints but I like doing like this

```
def check(l, thr1, thr2):
    c = [n > thr1 for n in l]
    if sum(c) >= thr2:
        return c.index(1)
```

Comment: Short, simple and fast! Thank you for the contribution! Will take this as a basis! (And thanks to all the other ones, all of them work nicely!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def check_list(testlist)
    overages = [x for x in testlist if x > thr1]
    if len(overages) >= thr2:
        return testlist.index(overages[0])
    # This return is not needed. Removing it will not change
    # the outcome of the function.
    return None
```

This uses the fact that you can use if statements in list comprehensions to ignore non-important values.

As mentioned by Chris_Rands in the comments, the `return None` is unnecessary. Removing it will not change the result of the function.

Comment: `return testlist.index(overages[0])`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Ah yes, thanks. Missed the index part of the question.

Comment: `return None` is unnecessary, Python will `return None` anyway

Comment: @Chris_Rands That's true, but it makes it clear to the OP what is happening. And it doesn't cost anything, so I think it is still good to have.

Answer (score 0):

A naive and straightforward approach would be to iterate over the list counting the number of items greater than the first threshold and returning the index of the first match if the count exceeds the second threshold:

```
def answer(l, thr1, thr2):
    count = 0
    first_index = None
    for index, item in enumerate(l):
        if item > thr1:
            count += 1
            if not first_index:
                first_index = index

            if count >= thr2:  # TODO: check if ">" is required instead
                return first_index

thr1 = 4
thr2 = 5

list1 = [1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 8]
list2 = [1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

print(answer(list1, thr1, thr2))  # prints 3
print(answer(list2, thr1, thr2))  # prints None
```

This is probably not quite pythonic though, but this solution has couple of advantages - we *keep the index of the first match only* and have an *early exit out of the loop* if we hit the second threshold.

In other words, we have `O(k)` in the best case and `O(n)` in the worst case, where `k` is the number of items before reaching the second threshold; `n` is the total number of items in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'd call it clean or pythonic, but this should work

```
def get_index(list1, thr1, thr2):
    cnt = 0
    first_element = 0
    for i in list1:
        if i > thr1:
            cnt += 1
            if first_element == 0:
                first_element = i

    if cnt > thr2:
        return list1.index(first_element)
    else:
        return "criteria not met"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thr1 = 4
thr2 = 5
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 8]
list2 = [1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

def func(lst)
    res = [ i for i,j in enumerate(lst) if j > thr1]
    return len(res)>=thr2 and res[0]
```

Output:

```
func(list1)
3
func(list2)
false
```

Comment: nice one! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one-liner (or almost)

```
a = filter(lambda z: z is not None, map(lambda (i, elem) : i if elem>=thr1 else None, enumerate(list1))) 
print a[0] if len(a) >= thr2 else false
```